# IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.2 importing inline instead of at the top of the file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have been using intelliJ IDEA for quite some time, upgrading as available.  Somehow it started auto adding the fully-qualified class name inline in the code instead of adding the import at the top of the file like it did for years.  I have not been able to change this behavior in settings which means I have to manually move the qualified names to the top as imports and delete them in the code. import cleanup does not move them either, not that it should. It's driving me insane but I cannot find a setting or anyone else having this problem so I thought I'd ask here.

Example: I type LocalDate somewhere in code and intelliJ expands it to:

```
java.time.LocalDate myDate = null;
```

instead of adding the import to the top:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
```

Comment: Inline import is definitely an incorrect syntax and not expected to be produced by Intellij Idea, this means that there should not be any settings for such a thing. If its happening to you, I would suggest filling a bug against the version showing this behaviour.

Comment: Do you mean that it’s using fully-qualified names _instead of_ imports? Can you include an example of the code it is producing in the question?

Comment: What is the kang, btw? Check **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | <language> | imports**. "Single class import" could do the trick

Comment: @TimMoore, thanks for the question, yes sorry that is what I mean, fully qualified names are being auto-inserted in-line instead of imported at the top of the file.  I will update my question. So instead of "import java.time.LocalDate;" at the top, I will see " java.time.LocalDate myDate = null;" in the code when I type LocalDate.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov It is Java.  I believe you pointed me to the correct setting.  I did have "single class import" set, but somehow I also had "use fully qualified class names" set.  I am not sure how that happened, and when I searched I was looking for "import".  Thanks to you and TimMoore.

Comment: If you post an answer @KonstantinAnnikov I will mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the fully qualified name is inserted in the code, instead of import statement, it is needed to tick the **Use fully qualified class names** option under **Preferences | Editor | Code Style |  | imports**.
See the difference:

[image]